# How to pass the solution of ode45 to be the initial condition in pdepe

Tags: matlab, math

I'm solving a 2nd order PDE using `pdepe`. The initial condtion of my problem is the solution of a 2nd order ODE, which I solved using `ode45`.  How can I pass the ode45 solution as my initial condtion in `pdepe` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would solve ode numerically and then create a function enveloping the function `interp1()` to get a value at any point using an interpolation method for the computed numerical data.